# IF UIButton was pressed Xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

Is it possible to have an if statement that looks if a button has been pressed?

```
if(condition) {
  //Do something
}
```

What has to go as the condition?

Comment: Typical UI programming is done through event handling. That is, you bind one (or more) functions to execute as a result of a UI event - such as a button being clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UIButton will call a method, to which it is wired up in Interface Builder or [set to in code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW4).

If you need to know in certain parts of your program, if a button was pressed, you can do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *) sender
{
    self.buttonPressed = YES; //bool instance variable with property
}

-(void)someOtherMethod
{
    if(self.buttonPressed){
        //do what you want to do, if button pressed
    }
}
```

But I think, coupling the UI and logic so tight on a semantic level, is no good idea.